# JSON output from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have data in my database as

```
COl1      | COL2
fruit     | apple, grape, berry
vegetable | tom, pot, leaf
```

If I query for fruit, I want COL2 to read for the query and data is split and output `echo json_encode($data)` should be in the form of:

```
[
  {input: "fruit", target: "apple"},
  {input: "fruit", target: "grape"},
  {input: "fruit", target: "berry"} ]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: some reason I feel your database does not follow any rules of Normalization..

Comment: Always provide information on what you have tried..cause you won't learn until you actually attempted anything..that said here is one way you will have to iterate through db rows explode your values and assign to new array and than send it to json_decode

Comment: Of course, Tomatoes are fruit, too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is how to format the col2 value into your target JSON format.
then do it like

```
$dbval =  "apple, grape, berry";
$fruits  = explode(",",$dbval);

$json = array();

foreach($fruits as $fruit) {

   $json[] = array("input"=>"fruit","target"=>$fruit);

}

echo json_encode($json)
```

sorry if i got the question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-think your database design. What do you think about tables like:

```
category
 - id 
 - name (e.q. fruit or vegetable)

food 
 - id 
 - name (e.q. apple, tom, pot, leaf, ...)

food_has_category
 - id (if necessary)
 - category_id
 - food_id
```

If you're not able to edit the database, try to explode the strings, modify the arrays as you want and encode them to JSON: http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php